# Does firestore keep a copy of the entire cloud database in local disk storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app which uses firestore now. I have enabled persistence. I just wanted to know if Firestore keeps a local copy of the entire cloud database or Just the stuff which is accessed by the app through queries.

Comment: Only content that was accessed by the client is persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local cache that the Firestore client only contains:

1. the data that your app has recently listened to, and
2. a queue of the write operations that the local client has performed, but that haven't been synchronized with the server yet